# Reading user input and stop on empty string

Tags: c, string, input, scanf

I want to read some user input and do something with each input. I do that using this code:

```
char c;
while(1){
    printf("input");
    c = scanf ( "%s", &c ) ;
}
```

This works fine . But I need it to accept even an empty input. But it just continues to next line and expects an not-empty input. How could I do that?

Current situation:

```
input:asdf
input:b
input:c
input:d
input:e
input:

fjhkjh
```

Expected :

```
input:asdf
input:b
input:c
input:d
input:e
input:blabla
input:f
input:
input:
```

Just how the cmd console works like...
UPDATE: I don't read only one single charcater, that was an example

Comment: You want `%c` instead of `%s`, and to get a simple `char` is better to use [getchar](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_getchar.htm) and print with [putchar](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_putchar.htm), declare `c` as `int`

Comment: `char c[3];//or more` .. `fgets(c, sizeof c, stdin);`

Comment: When I use `c = getchar()` it will print an `input:` for each charcater introduced on the line before...

Comment: @BLUEPIXY that worked, can you post it as an answer ? :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all You shouldn't use %s to store input in a single character as %s is for string of characters terminated by null character(\0).
Don't use **&** with **%s** in scanf().
To store a single character make use of:

```
scanf("%c",&c);
```

or

```
c = getchar();
```

Comment: Good to say that `c` should be declared as `int` instead of `char` using `getchar()` (in order to detect `EOF`)

Comment: @asdf, this was answered before your last edit, we can't read your mind :P

Comment: @AlterMann i know, my example was missleading, sorry about that

Comment: @asdf, no problem ;), then you want (as pointed out by @BLUEPIXY) `fgets`, but notice that the trailing newline is also included in the array.

Comment: Yes, I used that and chomped the newline. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your code,

```
  scanf ( "%s", &c ) ;
```

invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
, as you cannot fit an incoming *string* inside a `char`.

That said, `%s` skips the leading white-spaces and reads the non-white-spaces up to the immediate white-space and ignores the last white-space, so you cannot read *only* white-spaces using `%s`.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.2, `fscanf()`, (*emphasis mine*)

> `s` Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters.
>
> If no `l` length modifier is present, the corresponding argument shall be a
>   pointer to the initial element of a character array **large enough to accept the
>   sequence and a terminating null character,** which will be added automatically.

So, we can clearly see, `c` is no sufficient to hold even a single `char` input, either, it will be out of bound access to store the terminating null.

You seem to be in need to [`getchar()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) or similar.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't internally work like that, you have declared it as single char but you have used %s which is a char array. the char you get as input are stored as null values.. every character you gave a b c d e are taken as null..
if you have doubt, add a `printf("%s",c);` below the `scanf();`

Comment: `The char you get as input are stored as null values.` or not stored, or stored as garbage ... you can not predict the behavior of _undefined behavior_

Answer (score 0):

First you must have to use getchar(); or %c in scanf for a single character 
then you can use a if for test which is the input character

```
char c;
while(1)
{
 c=getchar();
 if(c==' ')
  break();
}
```

This is only for single character input.